# Renaming or deleting files in backed up location

Tags: windows-7, backup

I have set up a backup on Windows 7. The problem is that when I delete or rename a file in a backup, then the information about deletion or renaming is not backed up. So when I run restoration, all files, including the deleted ones, are restored.

1. Is it possible not to restore files that were deleted?
2. Or is there any alternative backup software that can do that?

Comment: If you have this, how could the software handle situations where you want to restore a deleted file? If you want a file gone from backups, you'll just have to delete it manually from all the backups. Some backup software allows you to edit backups.

Comment: @billc.cn: The software would handle it by versioning. I could then restore older backup where the file was not yet deleted. I don't need the file to be removed from backup. I just need to restore the exact state of a folder in the given time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Windows Backup, then you can do this using the Previous Versions.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Previous-versions-of-files-frequently-asked-questions

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want cloud backup, then I prefer Amazon S3 plus some backup program such as 2BrightSparks SyncBackPro or CloudBerry. They will both handle synchronization issues seamlessly (SyncBackPro has more powerful features, however its not as easy to use out of the box).